# Win10 File copy speed over network drops to 0

Tags: windows-10, home-networking, file-transfer

Copying files from desktop to drive attached to my router starts fast but quickly slows then stops. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

never had this problems But your question is poor in terms of description: 
no type of connection specified (ethernet or Wifi)
no wifi dongle specified
no router model specified

so i guess the standard  steps you should follow are:
if you are using wireless connection: 
1) if your dongle is a usb 3.0 device use it on a usb 3.0 port (if you have one)
2) check the signal your dongle receives from the router.
3) update your wifi dongle's drivers 
4) if nothing of these works try working with an ethernet connection.

if you're working with ethernet connection:
1) it's always a good thing to check your cables condition
2) since ethernet rarely brings problems try first restarting your router
3) if router still gives trouble try to upgrade its firmware